# A ring theory problem where i am given a power endomorphism and asked to show that R is either the field with 2 or 4 elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am given a ring R that is a division ring. The problem says that the function f(x)= x<sup>10</sup> is an endomorphism of the group (R,+), and I am asked to show that R is either the field with 2 or 4 elements.

It’s easy to show that f is injective and therefore plugging 1 and -1 gets you the characteristic of 2. After this I am stuck. I tried showing somehow that x^<sup>10</sup> =x for every element in the ring but i was unable to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best proof, but this should work.

By assumption, every element of $R$ is a root of the polynomial $(X+1)^{10}-X^{10}-1 \in \mathbb{F}_2[X]$, which is monic of degree $8$. In particular, $R$ is a division algebra of bounded degree over $\mathbb{F}_2$. Jacobson has proven that these are finite and also commutative.

> Jacobson, *Structure Theory for Algebraic Algebras*, Annals of Mathematics, Second Series, Vol. 46, No. 4 (Oct., 1945), pp. 695-707 (13 pages)

So $R$ is a finite field of characteristic $2$ of degree $\leq 8$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$. You can now exclude all the ones except for $\mathbb{F}_2$ and $\mathbb{F}_4$.

Comment: I don't really understand the hint, so perhaps it's also too cryptic for the OP.

Comment: I've expanded it a bit.

Comment: It is of degree $8$. Keep in mind that $10 x^9 = 0$.

Comment: Foot inserted in mouth